# The argument type 'Function' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function()?' Dart

Tags: function, dart, void

`import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Answer extends StatelessWidget {
  final Function selectHandler;

  Answer(this.selectHandler);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      color: Colors.pink,
      child: ElevatedButton(
        child: Text('Answer 1'),
        onPressed: selectHandler,
      ),
    );
  }
}`


[screenshot of vscode][1]

I got this code that I use from a Dart (flutter) YouTube course (that is from 2019) and i get an error on the last "selectHandler" (after onPressed) -> "The argument type 'Function' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function()?'" I don't really understand because it is working well in the video.
I am pretty sure that the course is too old but if you can help me that could be cool. Thanks ! (PS: my flutter doctor is good)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
final Function selectHandler;
```

with

```
final void Function() selectHandler;
```

see this [ref doc](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialButton/onPressed.html)

Comment: when I do this, I have more others problems. Effectivly, this one in particular is resolved but at the first "Function", I have "Expected to find ';'"  and when i add one it become even worst.

Comment: A fixed the syntax in the answer. It's `void Function()` as a function type.

Comment: see the edited.  @lrn  its typo^_^, thank you.